# Current post ID - relative url

Tags: url-rewriting

I need URL with some symbol instead post `id`?

For ex. I have:

`http:/example.org/?post_id=123`

And I need

`http://example.org/?post_id="current page symbol"`

How can I create it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings -> Permalink` and select Custom Structure.

Enter `/?post_id=%postname%` or `/?p=%postname%` in input then save changes.

Comment: Hi, Its not for permalink, I have the one button on all pages and I will redirect on http://example.org/editor/and_post_id - this "and_post_id" is "symbol" for post ids, this button adress must be that some on all posts, I have only one button.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the permalink below the title in Wordpress Post.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself: _"some page **symbol**"_? (Whatever that means).

Comment: @kaiser +1 for comment of the year. I really tried hard to understand what does a symbol mean. Probably he meant title or something.